# Generating Intermediate layer output of Vgg16

Tags: python, pytorch, layer, pre-trained-model, vgg-net

How can i generate intermediate layer output(third and forth MaxPool layer output) of VGG 16 in pytorch model.

pretrained_model = models.vgg16(pretrained=True)

Answer (score 0):

you can use forward hook as described here:
https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-can-l-load-my-best-model-as-a-feature-extractor-evaluator/17254/6

Alternatively, subclass the vgg16 model and manipulate its forward function.